# Firebase Storage putData method never executes completion block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image into Firebase storage and then save user profile into database.

But it seems that storageRef.putData method is not executed -> "in put data closure" is never printed. ("uploadProfileImage called" is printed.)

This is function which is called in Auth.auth().createUser closure.

```
func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
    print("uploadProfileImage called")
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")

    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
        print("In put data closure")
        if error == nil, metaData != nil {
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("url error")
                } else {
                    completion(url?.absoluteURL)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But I can see the image in firebase storage, so it was uploaded. And for saving profile I need url of this image.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `putData` is supposed to return upload task. Did you try to observe its status with `observeStatus` and see if there's an error?

Comment: Hey, I tried `storageRef.putData(imageData).obsserver(.progress) { (snapshot) in ..` and snapshot.error is always nil and snapshot.progress is: "Optional(<NSProgress: 0x600002291b80> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 19544 of 19544  )"

Answer (score 0):

Just fix 'FirebaseInstanceID' to version '2.0.0' in the podfile, putData method will be executed. It look like this in podfile:
      pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

I'm using Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5, the trick still works